# TypeError with irclib.py

Tags: python, arduino, irc

I'm trying to get this: http://blog.datasingularity.com/?p=148
to work. I've gotten pretty far, but I hit a brick wall, especially for someone who is as bad at programming as I am.

I get this error:

```
C:\windows\system32>python C:\Users\Jenna\Downloads\arduinoIRC\Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jenna\Downloads\arduinoIRC\Main.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Jenna\Downloads\arduinoIRC\Main.py", line 25, in main
    bot.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ircbot.py", line 246, in start
    self._connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ircbot.py", line 96, in _connect
    ircname=self._realname)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\irclib.py", line 1084, in connect
    localaddress, localport, ssl, ipv6)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\irclib.py", line 433, in connect
    self.socket.connect((self.server, self.port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Main.py

```
import Commands

from ArduinoBot import *
from Arduinos import Arduino     

def main():

    bot = ArduinoBot(Arduino(Commands.PORT, Commands.BAUD), Commands.CHANNEL,     Commands.NICK, Commands.SERVER, Commands.PORT)
    bot.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Commands.py
http://pastebin.com/kH7w9Mt3

Comment: Jenna, please show the code that produced this error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the contents of `Commands.py`

It seems like your handing it a string, where it is expecting an int.

Comment: EDIT: posted it in the original question

Comment: I got it working! i changed PORT (for the serial port) in commands.py and in main.py to SPORT and it works.